# Interrupt UITableView cell resize animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiviewanimation

I have a UITableView, and when it stops scrolling (scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:) the height of the current cell expands by setting the variable **currentRow** and reloading:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat current_offset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
    currentRow = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, current_offset)].row;
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
};
```

The animation works fine, but it temporarily prevents the tableview from being scrollable/interactive. So if I touch the screen while the cell is expanding, I end up not being able to scroll unless I try again.

Is there a workaround or another way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Maybe you can try to disable `userInteractionEnabled`(or other similar property) before the animation starts and enable it after the animation ends.

Comment: Maybe delaysContentTouches is enabled? I've had this exact problem though, and even disabling delaysContentTouches doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: There is no way to interrupt `UITableView` animations, unfortunately. Be sure to submit a bug report to Apple requesting this feature; don't forget to mark an answer as accepted before the bounty expires.

Comment: Why not try commit reloadData instead of beginUpdates and endUpdates? Also you can try commit Animations as well

Answer (score 4):

You can use this method, to stop animations,
but I'm not sure that it will not make problems.

```
- (void)stopAnimations
{
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
        [cell.layer removeAllAnimations];
    }
}
```

Try adding this on your TableViewController

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self stopAnimations];
}
```

or try to add tap gesture recognizer to Application's window and then call stopAinimations on gesture trigger.

Comment: Also not going to help. The animation is already in progress. How would you call stop based on a touch on the UITableView if touches are being ignored during animations?

Comment: I'm sure that tableView animation doesn't hangup mainThread, I think touchesBegan:withEvent: may be called and the animation can be terminated.

Comment: This assumes that the UITableView hasn't disabled user interaction, which I'm fairly certain it has.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons I think we can add listener to Navigation controller's view, or window. In this case tableView can't disable it.

Comment: Feel free to try it to achieve what the OP is asking. Not only would you have to stop the animation, but you would then have to apply the same scroll motion to the UITableView that the user attempted and which was intercepted. This is going to be horribly fragile and hacky.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons why you're minusing ?

Comment: This would work in theory, but there's a lot of conditional `super` handling that would need to happen and I suspect it would break more things than it would help.

Comment: @logger Not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

The UITableView animation system is completely opaque. There is no API that let's you modify or override what happens beyond selecting what type of animation occurs for inserts/deletes. Peruse the header file and look at the stack traces.

So, there is no practical way to prevent `UITableView` animations from blocking touches, nor should you want to. Doing so could lead to manipulating a dequeued cell. So, unless you are fond of `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` errors, don't do that.

Note that that user interactions are disabled for all `UITableView` animations, not just updates -- inserts, deletes, and reloads are handled the same way.

It seems like a reasonable hook to have into `UITableView` animations, though, so be sure to submit a [bug report to Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com/) and maybe we'll see it in a future enhancement.

Comment: That's all fine and dandy, but it should be possible to interrupt the animation on the table view something like UIAnimationOptionsAllowUserInteraction

Comment: Some references to support "it isn't" would be great - a single comment like that shouldn't be taken verbatim.

Comment: @remus The UITableView animation system is completely opaque. There is no API that let's you modify or override what happens beyond selecting what type of animation occurs for inserts/deletes. Peruse the header file and look at the stack traces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS 7+ you could try calling the table updates inside a `[UIView performWithoutAnimation:]` block.

Comment: All this will do is ensure that the row height transitions instantly. Not really addressing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to interrupt tableview animation also it is not advisable. If you want the tableview to be responsible on first touch you can use `reloadData` method instead of `beginUpdates` else try using `reloadSection` method. It may help but preventing the animation is not good idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this might help improve responsiveness, perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[CATransaction begin];

[self.tableView beginUpdates];


[CATransaction setCompletionBlock: ^{
    // Code to be executed upon completion
   CGFloat current_offset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
   currentRow = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, current_offset)].row;
}];


[self.tableView endUpdates];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Lastly you might want to commit animations also for the tableview

Comment: This might work great, but I'd like to see the OP validate before I award the bounty.

Comment: Confused -- the OP didn't ask to have a new row inserted, but to expand an existing row after scrolling stopped. Assuming you modify the code to do what the OP asked, putting the table updates inside a transaction is still not going to make the expand row animation interruptable.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons is correct. I'm not sure there is a solution. I've decided to go with a different design that just overlays information on top of the neighboring cells instead of trying to expand the cells.